# MySQL Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, csv

I have two tables: tblACTypeCharacteristics and tblAircrafts.

tblACTypeCharacteristics definition:

```
create table if not exists tblACTypeCharacteristics(
idAC_type        varchar(255) not null,
numPassengers    int,
primary key(idAC_type));
```

tblAircrafts definition:

```
create table if not exists tblAircrafts(
idAC       int not null auto_increment,
txtAC_tag  varchar(255) not null,
txtAC_type varchar(255) not null,
primary key(idAC, txtAC_tag));
```

In addition, I have added an foreign key like followed:

```
alter table tblaircrafts add foreign key(txtAC_type) 
        references tblactypecharacteristics(idAC_type);
```

In tblACTypeCharacteristics, the maximum number of passengers is defined for each type of aircraft.
In tblAircraft are all aircrafts available listed.
I am able to insert a new aircraft by typing for example:

```
insert into tblaircrafts (txtAC_tag, txtAC_type) values ('OE-LDA','A319-112');
```

But as there are loads of aircrafts around, I dont want to add each one by hand.
I want to import them by a csv file (I do have a list of a few aircrafts).
And I Import it as followed:

```
load data local infile 'C:\\Users\\t_lichtenberger\\Desktop\\tblAircrafts.csv'
into table tblaircrafts
character set utf8
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines;
```

But as I want to Import the .csv file into the tblaircraft table, I get the following error:

```
15:08:37    alter table tblaircrafts  add foreign key(txtAC_type) references tblactypecharacteristics(idAC_type)    Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pilotproject`.`#sql-11d0_2da`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-11d0_2da_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`txtAC_type`) REFERENCES `tblactypecharacteristics` (`idAC_type`))   0.641 sec
```

and I cannot explain why. The number of columns are the same and the datatypes of the columns are the same. And I have double-checked the csv for AC_types which arent in the tblACTypeCharacteristic tables and it should be good..

the first few rows of the csv file look like followed:

[image: first few lines of the aircraft csv]

Any suggestions why the error still occurs? 
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: A useful way to isolate the problem would be to drop or deactivate the foreign key, then import the rows. Assuming it imports successfully, you can then do a query to find which child rows have a key not in the parent table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution. I just disabled the foreign key checks by executing

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

before setting the foreign keys and it worked! I was able to add the csv records afterwards.

Comment: Are you able to turn the foreign key checks back on afterwards?

Comment: Yes I set the foreign keys checks back to 1 when I have added the records